# How do I go back and forth in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, logic

So I have a sequence of items at these indexes 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. I need to add middle two elements at first:

```
output = i[5]+i[6]
```

and for every next iteration, output must be add with left element and then right element.

```
output = output + i[4]
```

next step,

```
output = output + i[7]
```

I don't know how do that in loop or any other structure. Could anyone recommend anything to me? I'm working with python, but I just need pseudocode.

Comment: Do you need to do it specifically for this list or do you need a function that will apply to any other list?

Comment: @Batselot specifically for this list

Comment: I have come up with a solution for this, hope it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an element from either left or either right for each iteration I'd use a `while` statement in combination with a `pop()` on the `list`.

**Code**:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

total = 0

while len(l):
    total += l.pop(len(l) // 2)
```

**Output**:

```
print(total)
55
```

The `total` progression is:

```
0 + 6 = 6
6 + 5 = 11
11 + 7 = 18
18 + 4 = 22
22 + 8 = 30
30 + 3 = 33
33 + 9 = 42
42 + 2 = 44
44 + 10 = 54
54 + 1 = 55
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newlist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
while(len(newlist)>0):
    lengthi=(len(newlist)//2)-1
    lengthj=(len(newlist)//2)
    sum=(newlist[lengthi]+newlist[lengthj])
    del newlist[lengthi:(lengthj)+1]
    print(sum)
```

This works for the list I have tried it, however this will change according to the length of your list. This works for even, if the length changes the code gives errors because there will be a non matched element at the end. Also you can do this by not deleting the list by copying the variable into another variable and then deleting the variables from it is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

The common item here is that the two subscripts have to add up to 11.

```
output = 0
for left in range(5, 0, -1):
    right = 11 - left
    output += i[left]
    output += i[right]
```

I left the solution longer than necessary, since you seem to have other steps in between.

Comment: This solution takes elements from both left and right. there should be element from either left or either right for each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Well you can start from middle of the list and then as you go forward, add left and right elements together.

```
m = len(a)//2  # middle of the list
output = 0
for i in range(m):
    output += a[m-i-1] + a[m+i]
```

I'm trusting here that length of the list is an even number. Although odd length won't be a problem, just that the last element of list will be ignored.